# dropdown button not working on looping it in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am working in Angular ,

- Where I have created a tree based structure
- on going down to tree structure there is a dropdown button name
  "Dropdown"
- **Problem is** on clicking to  "**Dropdown**" **button dropdown is not working .**

**Kindly check I am putting stackblitz link below for the code**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-un?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Could you provide relevant code into your question?

Comment: If you inspect the DOM, you'll see that the dropdown div is inserted in the DOM. its css class is dropdown-content, and this class sets display to none, so even if they're in the DOM, you can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes please see whether it's as per your expected output or not.

`Ts file`

```
myFunction(value) {
console.log(value);
if (value == 1) {
  this.availableBtn = !this.availableBtn;
}

if (value == 2) {
  this.vaccanttoggle = !this.vaccanttoggle;
 }
}
```

`HTML  File`

```
<div id="myDropdown" *ngIf="availableBtn">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
```

seems like there is problem with `class="dropdown-content"`. remove it and try.